# Why doesnt Conditional Variational AutoEncoders(CVAE) cluster data like the vanila VAE?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

I have a hard time understanding why a Conditional VAE, doesn't cluster the data-points the way vanilla VAEs do!
I was expecting to see the same or at least similar looking plots when I tried to visualize the latent variable `z`? 
Here is how a vanilla VAE looks like : 
[image]
and this is how a conditional one looks like : 
[image]

both of them have around the same loss, and produce plausible outcome so its not  like the Conditional VAE is not trained properly. 
What is the intuition behind this behavior? How should I interpret what is going on here?
How does it know how to produce different classes( digits in my case), when everything seems to be messed up like this in the manifold?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a conditional VAE, the approximate posterior is already conditioned on the class -- $q(z|X,c)$, so there is no need for the latent space to separate the class of each input.

> How does it know how to produce different classes

The decoder is also conditioned on the class.

> How should I interpret what is going on here?

The latent space is probably modeling other types of "style" -- thickness, tilt, size, etc of the digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it, but can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: @Breeze the latent space no longer has to model the digit class, because the network is already given the digit class. Therefore the latent space is freed up to do something else. Let me know exactly what you want more details on

Comment: My question I guess is, what does the new encodings refer to then? what are they representing? in vanilla vae, the new embeddings, refered to all possible values a specific class could take, and they would provide smooth bounderies between classes where we could gradually morph from one class into another. 
But here, its still the same vae, however we just conditioned it on a label, in my mind, I'm trying to visualize what is happening. what its doing. the network must come to a cluster for each class, so that when we sample, we get different variations of each class. but looking

Comment: at the visualization, everything is intermingled! its a soup of all classes all scattered around eachother as if they are all the same! how is this the network, deal with all the variations for each class?

Comment: "the network must come to a cluster for each class, so that when we sample, we get different variations of each class. but looking". no, the decoder is class-conditioned, so the latent space *does not* have to model interclass variation

Comment: The variations for 1s are very different than the variations for lets say 7, 8 or 5. how does the network know, which variation belongs to which class then? let me say this, is this visualization really a good indication of how data are located in the 2d manifold? or this visualization is just plain wrong? What can I infer by looking at this kind of visualization when there is no clustering happening ? is it even practiced? I mean do people really look at this and get idea if things are good or bad? if so how do they decide by looking at that?

Comment: Hi, in CVAE, when inputs an input sample (the label is known) and gets the `z`, how can I use this `z` to decode different outputs of which labels are different from the one of the original input?